# How include scopes write in module included by other module to a class? (rails 4.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, scope, include, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have a module like

```
module FooConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def self.included(klass)
    klass.instance_eval do
      scope :deleted, -> { where(state: STATE_DELETED) }
      scope :closed, -> { where(state: STATE_CLOSED) }
      scope :opened, -> { where(state: STATE_OPENED) }
    end
  end


  included do
    def deleted?
      state == STATE_DELETED
    end


    def closed?
      state == STATE_CLOSED
    end


    def opened?
      state == STATE_OPENED
    end
  end
end
```

and other module like :

```
module Bar
  include FooConcern
  include LotConcern
  include OfConcern
  include OtherConcern
  include ModuleConcern
end
```

and class using Bar :

```
class Baz
  include Bar
end
```

The error : `wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)` module Bar include Foo before being included in class, so I think it can't give the paramater.

If I put scopes directly in block `included do`, raise error : `undefined method 'scope' for Bar:Module`

How can I do to includes my scope by module itself include by module?

Answer (score 0):

I found this way, if you have better...

```
def self.included(klass)
  klass.instance_eval do
    include FooConcern
  end
end
```

in Bar module